# .ASPXROLES membership roles cookie expiry

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-2.0

Using ASP.NET 2.0, with forms authentication.
Just for a test, I configured the roles cookie in web.config like this :

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPXROLES" cookieTimeout="2"></roleManager>
```

I wanted to see what would happen when the cached role cookie expired. 
Using Fiddler, after 2 minutes had elapsed, I could see that the raw value of the role cookie had changed.

I was expecting that on expiry, that ASP.NET would simply re-read the roles information from the database, and repopulate the cookie with the same value. So my question is, why would the raw value of the cookie change after expiry ? The cookie value is not human-readable (base 64 encoded and/or encrypted ?), so I can't tell if the information in it is the same, although the application still seems to work fine.

**EDIT :**

It looks like each time the roles are encrypted and cached in the cookie, it gets a different raw value.

e.g. if you run the following code :

```
    RolePrincipal rp = (RolePrincipal) User;
    string str = rp.ToEncryptedTicket();
    Label1.Text = str;
```

You get a different value each time.
So the behavior seems normal.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense with encryption, to a degree. It may depend on what you're doing with your encryption keys in your web.config. I'll edit my question and add some content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `aspxroles` cookie only pertains to role queries on the user. Unless you're doing things with the roles that would cause it to function differently (web.config auth?) then you're not going to see anything by expiring the cookie.

Can you share your web.config and basic pages that you're using to test this?

Have you tried that particular configuration to see what changes after the expiration?

```
<location path="img/logo.png">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow roles="CanSeeLogo"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

---

Based on the question edit:

In my web.config under `<configuration><system.web>` I have this key:

```
<machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="{64bits random hex}" validation="SHA1" validationKey="{128 bits random hex}"/>
```

I'm curious if you set that "manually" if you'll have a constantly changing encrypted string. Also, this is set by default in your C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\etc folders, but you can redefine it (obviously) in your web.config to override it per application. This also allows you to share the same cookie cross-app within your domain.

Link to generate random hex strings

https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm

concat the first result from two page refreshes for the second one. Removing the web.config key later doesn't impact your app negatively (of course it wouldn't)

Comment: thanks for responding drachenstern. See my edit - it looks like this is just how the encryption algorithm works.

Comment: I tried adding the machine key as suggested - it still gives a constantly changing encrypted string.

Comment: @MoeSisko ~ Thanks for testing it, I've never tried that and wasn't sure. I guess then it's a hash that's generated by the engine. I've never tried to Reflect that code, but I'm sure it's available in RedGate Reflector. I can look into this later if you like, to see what the code is that generates that cookie, but for now pressing matters press on. You might check into reflecting that if you've never used Reflector.